# Getting None after return the function

Tags: python

hello there i created a function with Python to get some data as you see in code

```
def do_func (path, events_count = 0):
  # Openning the connection and grap the page
  u_client = uReq(url)
  page_html = u_client.read()
  u_client.close()

  # html parser
  page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
  data = {}
  data['name'] = page_soup.find("name").text
  
  events = page_soup.find_all("events")
  events_count += len(events)
  data["events"] = events_count

  next_page = page_soup.find("nex_page")
  if (next_page):
    do_func(next_page, events_count)
  else:
    print(data)
    return data

print(do_func(url))
```

but after executing the function getting None

and if i use print(data) inside the function, i'm getting the object

Comment: `return do_func(next_page, events_count)`

Comment: You have no `return` in the True branch of `if (next_page):`, so _of course_ it returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (next_page):
    do_func(next_page, events_count) # <-- does not return anything when executed
else:
    print(data)
    return data
```

maybe it should look like:

```
if (next_page):
    data = do_func(next_page, events_count) 
else:
    print(data)
return data
```

or

```
if (next_page):
    return do_func(next_page, events_count) 
else:
    print(data)
    return data
```

?